# Swapping speed of ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to make a control show different values depending on a nearby checkbox.  The code that I'm using is very similar to this:

```js
(function (angular) {
  var module = angular.module('test', ['ngAnimate']);
  
  module.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.profile = [
      { key: 'Prop1', value: 'test', localValue: 'test2', local: true },
      { key: 'Prop2', value: 'hello', localValue: 'world', local: false },
    ];
  }]);
  
})(angular);
        
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['test']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.23/angular-animate.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form data-ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="prop in profile">
    <label class="control-label">{{prop.key}}</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="prop.local" />
      </span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly"
             data-ng-if="!prop.local" data-ng-model="prop.value" />
      <input class="form-control" type="text"
             data-ng-if="prop.local" data-ng-model="prop.localValue" />
      <span class="input-group-addon" data-ng-if="!prop.local">(inherited)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When the checkbox is toggled there is a brief moment when both input fields are visible at the same time, causing undesirable layout effects.  It does appear correctly in the end, but I'm hoping to eliminate the lag and have them swap smoothly.  (I'm assuming this is a JS performance issue related to having a lot more properties on the page, or a lot more other stuff going on elsewhere on the page.)

Is there a way I can rewrite this to get the desired effect with improved performance?  Is it possible to swap just the binding instead of the whole control?  Or can anyone think of something else that might be causing the delay?

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose a problem when all we have is a correctly working example.  Can you duplicate your own code in a plunker and show the undesired effect?

Comment: I understand that the above is a snippet. Does the page on your application have more angular functionality? Also, ng-if adds/removes elements from the dom.

Comment: Yes, the page has a lot more angular functionality going on, which is why I said I suspected a performance problem.  I can't post more of it though.

Comment: The undesired effect is that when ticking or unticking the checkbox, both input elements are briefly visible on the page, which causes it to grow to two lines (since both are 100% width elements).  A moment later the "wrong" one disappears, but it is very noticeable.  I have already looked through all the CSS to see if there is an animation property or similar in effect, but there is not, at least not at the level of the input element itself.

Comment: Also note that using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` instead of `ng-if` has the same effect.

Comment: I've updated the example to replicate the failure, thanks to [Rouby's hint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29669395/43534) that merely including ngAnimate was the culprit.  (I had thought that this didn't do anything unless you specifically added animation attributes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by `ngAnimate`.

To disable the animations you need to disable them on the containing element.

```
app.directive('disableAnimate', function ($animate)
{
    return function (scope, element)
    {
        $animate.enabled(false, element);
    };
});
```

You can use the above directive on the container and it should disable the undesired effect.

Here is a plnkr with your example (without the effect and with ngAnimate).

http://plnkr.co/edit/3rb4yI0qg9z7HRdmsrFG?p=preview

Note that if your remove the directive you get the undesired effect even in this plnkr :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that was indeed the culprit.  I'll probably keep using the value-twiddling solution for the moment (since I have it working already), but I'll keep this in mind because it's bound to come up again.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I'm working around this issue by juggling the internal values rather than the control:

```js
(function (angular) {
  var module = angular.module('test', []);
  
  module.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.profile = [
      { key: 'Prop1', inheritedValue: 'test', localValue: 'test2', local: true },
      { key: 'Prop2', inheritedValue: 'hello', localValue: 'world', local: false },
    ];
    
    $scope.initValue = function (prop) {
      prop.value = prop.local ? prop.localValue : prop.inheritedValue;
    }
      
    $scope.localise = function (prop) {
      if (!prop.local) {
        // save last local value when switching local -> inherited
        prop.localValue = prop.value;
      }
      $scope.initValue(prop);
    }
  }]);
  
})(angular);
        
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['test']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form data-ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="prop in profile">
    <label class="control-label">{{prop.key}}</label>
    <div class="input-group" data-ng-init="initValue(prop)">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="prop.local"
               data-ng-change="localise(prop)" />
      </span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text"
             data-ng-readonly="!prop.local"
             data-ng-model="prop.value" />
      <span class="input-group-addon" data-ng-if="!prop.local">(inherited)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

It's a bit messier but it seems to work better.  Still curious if there are any better solutions.